# How do I evaluate whether the mean squared error (MSE) is reasonable or not?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

I'm creating regression models using scikit learn.
Now I'm wondering how I can evaluate whether the mean squared error is reasonable or bad?
For example, when I do cross validation, the testing data's MSE for model of train data is 0.70. Is it reasonable or bad score?
 Also is it meaningful to calculate the whole data's MSE for a model and compare them and see if the scores are similar?
It's not programming question but I want to know how to evaluate the value. I'm not sure if my way is correct or not.

Comment: The MSE value of 0.70 by itself makes answering that part of your qustion difficult - for instance, if I ask the same question after modeling experimental data with units of meters or kilometers it would still be the same model. In addition to using MSE, consider using the R-squared (R2) value calculated as "R2 = 1.0 - (absolute_error_variance / dependent_data_variance)". This can be interpreted as telling you how much of the data variance is explained by the model. If R2 = 0.5, then the model explains 50 percent of the data variance. If the R2 is 0.99 then the model explains 99 percent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you should use MSE or other regression performance metrics ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#regression-metrics)) is to compare different models (or same models with different hyperparamaters). If you keep your data set constant then it will give you an idea about what models perform better and which worse.

Let me suggest 2 benchmark regression models to always compare your sophisticated model to. If you are not able to beat these in terms of test MSE (or others) you are doing something wrong

1. Dummy regressor [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor.html#sklearn.dummy.DummyRegressor)
2. Linear regression [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

Comment: Thanks for tips.
So does it make sense to calculate MSE for whole data and MSE for testing data and compare them and see if it's similar and also the model is reasonable?

Comment: Split your data into train and test, fit the models on train and then evaluate on test. Pick the model that performs the best in terms of your selected performance metric.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got what you mean.